# How can I align 3 adjacent divs with two of them filling the available space?

Tags: html, css, alignment

[image]

div1: width = wrap_content, maximum 50px

div2, div3: fill half the remaining space each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2">
    <div class="div21"></div>
    <div class="div22"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.div1{
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    background-color:Red;
}

.div2{
    overflow:hidden;
}

.div21{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    background-color:green;
}

.div22{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

`div2` is something like a container and `div21` and `div22` equal `div2` and `div3` in your question.

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o6za8331/2/)**

Comment: Check the updated code, previous code has some issues.